# Jacobian of the change of variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The question is: Prove that the volume bounded by the ellipsoid $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$ is $4\pi abc/3$ using the change of variables formula.

Let $x=a\rho $sin$\varphi $cos$\theta$, $y=b\rho $cos$\varphi $cos$\theta$, $z=c\rho $cos$\varphi $,

then we can use the change of variables formula.

However, the answer says the Jacobian of the change of variables $x$, $y$, $z$ is $abc\rho^2 $sin$\varphi$ but I just did not get this answer... I don't think there is anything wrong with my computation of the determinant.

This is my work: We need to compute the determinant of

$\begin{bmatrix}
a \sin \varphi \cos \theta  & a\rho \cos\varphi \cos\theta  & -a\rho \sin\varphi \sin\theta \\ 
b\cos\varphi \cos\theta  &  -b\rho \sin\varphi \cos\theta & -b\rho \cos\varphi \sin\theta \\ 
 c\cos\varphi \ &  -c\rho \sin\varphi & 0
\end{bmatrix}$.

Is here anything wrong? Why I did not get $abc\rho^2 $sin$\varphi$?

Can anyone show me why the Jacobian of the change of variables is $abc\rho^2 $sin$\varphi$? Thanks so much.

Comment: Can you show your working?

Comment: @wj32: I've edited my post. Thanks.

Comment: (slightly off topic) A simple way to obtain the volume of an ellipse, is to consider a stretch in the x, y, z directions to the unit sphere.

Comment: @CalvinLin: isn't this coordinate transformation precisely what you are talking about?

Comment: @RonGordon I'm saying that we can avoid the Jacobian.

Comment: Maybe it would help to show what you did and what you got.

Comment: @Ian : It is unclear from your question whether you absolutely have to use the change of variables that you gave in your question.  If you don't Calvin Lin's suggestion is the way to go.  Oops, I just read to the bottom of your quesiton, and if "the answer" you refer to mentions $\varphi$ then I guess you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your coordinate transformation in $y$ is wrong.  It should be

$$x = a \rho \sin{\phi} \cos{\theta}$$

$$y = b \rho \sin{\phi} \sin{\theta}$$

$$z = c \rho \cos{\phi}$$

Comment: But I still not get $abc\rho^2 $sin$\varphi$.

Comment: Check your work - I did.  Verified in Mathematica.